# Can the zero vector be within the eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenfunctions

I have a matrix that looks like this: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 4 \\
    2 & 4 & 2 \\
    4 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now the calculated eigenvalues are: $-3$, $2$ and $7$. For the eigenvalue $-3$, I want to calculate the eigenspace and the basis. So after a little bit of rearranging I get to this matrix: 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc@{}|@{}c}
    4 & 2  & 4 & 0 \\
    0 & 12 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0  & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

So now, the rank is two and the dimension of the nullsapce is $1$. Second line: $12 v_2 + 0 v_3 = 0$, everything goes to zero and my basis is then $(0, 0, 0)$. But can this be within the eigenspace or did I just have make a fault?

Comment: You've said a few things with imprecise terminology and then some things that don't really make sense. I think your mathematical thinking is close to correct (you've just made a minor arithmetic error) but your way of expressing it seems confused. (1) eigenvectors are, well, vectors, the numbers you quoted are eigenvalues, (2) the nullspace is a subspace of the domain so can't be a number, perhaps you mean it has dimension 1 (the dimension of the null space is also called the "nullity") (3) please be clearer about what exactly you mean by "everything goes to zero".

Comment: As to your title question, the origin lies in every vector subspace.

Comment: I see you've corrected (1), but your correction to (2) just says "the dimension is $1$", without being clear *what* has dimension $1$. Of course I know from context that you mean "the dimension of the null space" but please be more careful to say these things clearly, otherwise people reading your questions have to do extra work.

Comment: I'm sorry, my english isn't that well. So, if I want $0 v_1 + 12 v_2 + 0 v_3 = 0$ I finally get $12 v_2 = 0 v_3$ and this results to that $v_1 = v_2 = v_3 = 0$ and so my basis is $(0, 0, 0)$

Comment: The free variable in the system is the third one; the vector you get is $(1,0,-1)$

Comment: @egreg Can you please explain, what do you mean by "free variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reduced to solve the system
\begin{cases}
4x_1+2x_2+4x_3=0\\[4px]
12x_2=0
\end{cases}
This implies $x_2=0$ and so $x_1+x_3=0$. So a vector in the eigenspace must be of the form
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\0\\-a
\end{bmatrix}
so the vector
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\-1
\end{bmatrix}
forms a basis of the eigenspace.

Comment: Now I got what you mean, this makes sense. Thank you.